# Overflow scrollbar in popover window not working (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a couple of popovers on my site that contain a number of a href tags. For most of the popovers there's no problem in terms of height. However, two of them require an overflow/scrollbar solution.

This is what I have tried so far but it does not appear to work:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Yeast & Mould" data-content='<ul><li><a href="First link"</a></li>
      <li><a href="Second link"</a></li>
      <li><a href="Multiple links"</a></li>
      </ul>
    </a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true;});
});     
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.popover-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Any ideas as to how I can resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: set a max height to the popover. then it will scroll

Comment: Brilliant. It is indeed as easy as that. Works like a charm. Cheer bud.

Comment: Great :) .. happy coding

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Reddy suggested in his comment, setting a max height to the popover resolves this issue. Thanks Reddy!